# How to orderBy a value returned after function call which is in loop?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-orderby

I am looping an object in view and calling a function which takes its members as parameters.

The function returns me a value every time the function is called.

I want to orderBy that returned value.

But my problem is, that value is returned after function call and I cannot store the values in an array so that I can sort.

```
    <div ng-repeat="member in current_project.members | orderBy : '?'"> 
     <span class="taskCompletionEst">
       Estimated time: 
             {{estimatedTimeSum(selected_date, member.id)}} hrs
     </span>
```

Controller

```
      $scope.estimatedTimeSum = function(date, member_id) {
       sum = 0
       angular.forEach($scope.projects[0].tasks[date], function(task, 
       projectname) {
        angular.forEach(task, function(value, key) {
         if (value["user_id"] == member_id) {
          if (value["completion"] != undefined) {
           sum += parseInt(value["estimation"])
          } 
         else {
          sum += parseInt(value["estimated_time"])
         }
        }
      });
    });
  return sum
 }
```

I need to orderBy Estimated time sum.

Comment: you will have to write a custom filter to incorporate the function call into the `ng-repeat`.  If you provide a more complete code example, particularly showing a sample of your data and how this function works, it will be easier to provide a more complete answer.  Right now, we can only offer vague suggestions, or try to write our own contrived example of what you *might* be trying to accomplish.

Comment: Can you post you controller too ? its hard to know the problem. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap your `estimatedTimeSum` function into intermediate `sort` function, which will be passed to `orderBy` filter:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.current_project = {
    members: [{
      id: 10
    }, {
      id: 250
    }, {
      id: 300
    }, {
      id: 150
    }, {
      id: 70
    }, {
      id: 800
    }]
  }; 

  $scope.sort = function(date) {
    return function(member){            
      return $scope.estimatedTimeSum(date, member.id);
    }    
  }

  $scope.estimatedTimeSum = function(date, member_id) {
    //only to  stub
    return member_id % (date || 1);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>
  <input type='number' ng-model='selected_date' ng-init='selected_date = 11'/>
  <div ng-repeat="member in current_project.members | orderBy : sort(selected_date)">
    <span class="taskCompletionEst">
       {{member.id}} Estimated time: {{estimatedTimeSum(selected_date, member.id)}} hrs
     </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Should the function not return array so that the sort works?

Comment: `ng-repeat="member in current_project.members | orderBy : 'sortEstTime(member)'"`

In Controller

` $scope.sortEstTime = function(member){
    angular.forEach($scope.current_project.members, function(member) {  
      console.log(member)
      return $scope.estimatedTimeSum($scope.date, $scope.member_id);
      })
  } `

Comment: Function should return value, by which array will be sorted.

Comment: Thank you Mr @Slava Utesinov

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="member in current_project.members | orderBy:'modelProperty'"> 
 <span class="taskCompletionEst">
   Estimated time: 
         {{estimatedTimeSum(selected_date, member.id)}} hrs
 </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare the list of estimated time first in the controller. Then show the list in order.